# UIButton in UITableViewCell jumps on reloadRowsAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm facing this weird issue where each cell in my table has UIButton only, When i do change selected state of it so that set title color of Normal, selected take place, it gets a jumpy effect. Have not been able to identify yet. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Some code -
To reload rows -

```
`tableView.beginUpdates()
 tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(Array(selectedIndexPaths), withRowAnimation: .None)
 tableView.endUpdates()`
```

To set titlecolor and titleimage in cell class -

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    selectionButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(named: .SomeColor), forState: .Normal)
    selectionButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(named: .SomeColor), forState: .Selected)
    selectionButton.setImage(someimage, forState: .Normal)
    selectionButton.setImage(someimage, forState: .Selected
}
```

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: In real device to?

Comment: some code would be helpful

Comment: Yes, i real device as well

Answer (score 0):

I thought of commenting first but it seems that I need to have 50 reputation points to do that, so here it goes.

The reason that you getting this behaviour might be due to the custom row height that you are setting. If this is the case you can prevent it by giving estimated height for the rows.